# Is there a way to alter section numbering in lyx?

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

The problem I have is this, after entering a new part in LyX the section numbering doesn't reset and i haven't been able to make it myself. Using the image as reference, I want to be able to make section E numbered as `II.1` and section F as `II.1.1` and so on. For clarification, I am using L.y.X 2.3.7 and the document is in the default class, thatis , article. Thank you for your consideration and time.

[image: Reference image]

Comment: Are you sure, that you want parts and not chapters? If you are sure, you can add `\counterwithin*{section}{part}` to the document preamble (available via the document settings).

Comment: That is what I was looking for! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Number of book chapters usually don’t restart in part. LyX (LaTeX) default is based in the traditional convention. What you think the natural way would seem strange for others.